# php curl_getinfo set multiple opt parameters

Tags: php, curl

How can I specify more then one `$opt` parameter in [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) function?

I've tried these options but none of this works:

```
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_getinfo($ch, array(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE + CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

(There is nothing else to add to this question but the 'clever' quality check does not let me post this without additional text, lame but well it perfectly reflects the current stackoverflow state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. It's only for one option at a time.